# What feature selection methods to implement for logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, logistic, classification, feature-selection, unbalanced-classes

I tried several ways of selecting predictors for a logistic regression in R. I used lasso logistic regression to get rid of irrelevant features, cutting their number from 60 to 24, then I used those 24 variables in my stepAIC logistic regression, after which I further cut 1 variable with p-value of approximately 0.1. What other feature selection methods I can or even should use? I tried to look for Anova correlation coefficient analysis, but I didn't find any examples for R. And I think I cannot use correlation heatmap in this situation since my output is categorical? I seen some instances recommending Lasso and StepAIC, and other instances criticising them, but I didn't find any definitive comprehensive alternative, which left me confused.

I asked the above yesterday, but it was closed, so I provide further details below.

My sample is 300,000+ observations, so the number of variables isn't really the issue. The issue is their weak prediction power. The binary classification of the default/fully-paid loan classes I am doing has class imbalance of about 1:7, although it is not severe, it shows with PR-AUC scores of logreg, rf and xgboost models all under 30%. The accuracy with standard 0.5 threshold is 80%+ for these models, but such measures are irrelevant in classifications like this, where failing to correctly predict a default loan comes with high penalty. I know I have to try cost-sensitive modelling instead for better results, however I still need to show the low performance of standard approach ML models for my research. But a model like this logreg is giving only 60% sensitivity and 50% specifictiy after thresholding and about 65% accuracy at best, so I wanted to at least increase it's performance by conducting a proper feature selection procedure. And after all, I am still going to use this logistic regression IV set for the cost sensitive one, where it will basically just have weighted classes.

I first asked it on StackOverflow hoping that someone will share their usual feature selection procedure for logistic regression with code, but I was redirected here due to "more methodological nature" of my question, which is true ultimately; however, I would still highly appreciate links to code, examples of relevant feature selection methods, if anyone kindly shares them with me. Otherwise, I still would be happy to receive any purely theoretical advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where failing to correctly predict a default loan comes with high penalty.

An astute observation. A good question might be "when is the loan worth risking the high penalty?".

You should not be classifying observations as default/not default in this scenario, but rather modelling the risk that the customer will not pay back the loan.  With an appropriate risk model, you can then use a utility function to make decisions about if future loans should be awarded, rationally answering the question of when the risk of default is worth the possible reward.  [Frank Harrell writes more on the forced choice classification puts upon us](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/) and how treating problems probabilistically is a better approach. I suggest you read this post prior to continuing.

Additionally, I find that [you really shouldn't be selecting features, you should be engineering new ones](https://dpananos.github.io/posts/2020/12/blog-post-28/).  If all you're doing is looking at linear effects, you're likely missing out on additional model performance.  Non-linear models like random forests may be able to learn non-linear effects, however you still need to make sure the resulting fit is well calibrated before using it.

All in all, I think your approach needs to be revisited.  It sounds like you're modelling loan defaults, which is very well studied and is best approached as a risk modelling problem and not a classification problem.

Comment: I agree with you that a risk modelling approach is best for most such cases. However, in my paper, I am focusing on online p2p loans for individual investors there, who often do not have the luxury of being able to afford much losses; and a complex portfolio selection model would be out of the scope of my masters dissertation, thus I focus purely on default prediction. Moreover, the default predictions do give out probabilities, the predictions are defined later with thresholding; my guess is that the better the predictions perform, the higher the quality of probabilities given by the model.

Comment: Also, I did some feature engineering with categorical variables, however the vast majority are continuous and I don't really see a way to do anything further in regards to feature engineering with my data set.